# How to create library from the template [REST API or GRAPH]

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Is there a way to create library based on the custom template with use of REST or GRAPH API?

If not, I will:
Create Library + Add a Content Type + Add columns to default view :/

Answer (score 1):

When you create a list or library using Microsoft Graph you can specify the template.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request&WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698

[image: Microsoft Graph request]

Comment: I have crated the library template following this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/lists-custom-template
When I run PS: Get-SPOListDesign it returns:
Id               : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Title            : T123
SiteScriptIds    : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Description      : CustomTemplate
ThumbnailUrl     : 
TemplateFeatures : {}
Version          : 1
ListColor        : DarkRed
ListIcon         : Bug

Comment: Graph API body: 
{ "displayName": "FromGraph",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "Author",
            "text": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "PageCount",
            "number": {}
        }
    ],
    "list": {
        "template": "T123"
    }
}
and Error: 
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "badArgument",
            "date": "2022-03-22T08:56:01",
            "request-id": "",
           "client-request-id": ""

Comment: I think this is a naming overload issue. I'm pretty sure the list templates described in the article you linked are not the same list templates traditionally used in SharePoint (see link). I don't know of a way to programmatically create a list using a template created with Add-SPOListDesign.  

 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf

Comment: Yep, It looks like there is difference between OOB templates and custom templates.